# Adding images to a running JBoss web application

Tags: java, file-upload, jboss, ftp, load-balancing

We have a web application that allows users to upload photos which will then be displayed in a specified page after upload. The upload module places the images inside the exploded war directory, e.g. `webapp-root/uploads/` such that once the image is uploaded, it can be viewed instantly, as in `http://mydomain.com/uploads/123.png`.

This was working with one application server, but as it turns out, we were to deploy this app to 2 load-balanced servers. So I coded a quick file-sync module that syncs files between servers using FTP, whenever users upload images. Basically when a user uploads an image on `server1/uploads/`, I immediately copy it via FTP to `server2/uploads/`.

*Edit (added upload process):* The upload goes something like this:

- User selects and submits image
- Server saves file in `server1/uploads/`
- Background thread does an FTP sync from server1 to `server2/uploads/` (done async)
- Vice versa for server2

At this point, I'm running into problems.

The url `http://mydomain.com` uses a hardware load balancer to point to either server1 or server2. If a user uploads an image `test-image.png` to server1 (which is then synced to server2), I assume that I can access the image through `http://mydomain.com/uploads/test-image.png` regardless of whether the load balancer directs me to server1 or server2.

This isn't the case however. Continuing with the example, an image uploaded when the domain is pointed to server1 can only be viewed when `http://mydomain.com/uploads/test-image.png` is redirected to server1, and it appears as a broken link if a second user accesses the *same* url but the load balancer directs him to server2.

So it seems like JBoss isn't refreshing the second server whenever I FTP-copy an image inside its war directory. Which is kind of weird since if I upload an image to server1, the JBoss instance on that server serves up the image file without any problems.

Any way to manually tell JBoss that "hey, we have a new image file here"?

Comment: If the Jboss instances do not know of each other - being in a cluster - consider uploading to a database instead.

Comment: Yes, we've considered that (and will keep considering that as a fallback), however, at this stage we're looking for alternative solutions that will take less rework.

Comment: Do the JBoss instances know of each other?  If not your upload procedure MUST upload to all instances.

Comment: I see. I've edited the question with upload details. The process does copy the image to both instances (1 of which is through FTP). Does that satisfy the upload condition or does it have to be through an explicit file upload over HTTP?

Comment: The fundamental problem is that you break the Java EE API by manipulating the filesystem without telling the application server.  HOW you manipulate the file system is another matter (which is what you try to patch up with virtual duct tape).  I would suggest that you rethink your upload procedure.

Comment: Noted. I am aware it is a duct tape situation, born out of simply inadequate time and resources. I have already highlighted the necessity to change this to our team, but this process will have to do for the meantime. Thanks for sharing your observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've narrowed the issue to corrupted files on the receiving server. It would seem like the file permissions/encryption on the particular drive are preventing my FTP server from copying the images successfully which is why all my synced images cannot be viewed in any image viewer.

I'll have to try and resolve these user permission problems. Meanwhile I'll keep this question open in case anyone can shed some more light on other probable causes.